# Python : compare in looping

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I have an array that look kinda like this
A = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4]

Edited:
I tried doing with for looping and while I can't seem to get it right
For u guys can see the peak is 8 and the valley is 0
My desperate move is repeatedly typing if
If A[0] < A[1] :
 If A[1] < A[2]:
...

Until it wasn't right (A[7] < A[8]) (wrong)
Then some array need to save the value of A[7] say z

And I want the loop to stop everytime z catch a value

This is only the inner loop, I still need another outer loop so it can detect various valley point based on the peak point.

Comment: What have you tried so far? While occasionally people are very generous and might answer a question as incomplete as this one, you're much more likely to get help if you're already tried to solve the problem yourself and can show your efforts and describe what is going wrong with your attempted solution.

Comment: You see, from your question we can't tell if you know the `<` and `>` operators or not, if you know how to iterate over a list (it's not an array), if you know basic built-in functions like `max()`, or even what the desired output is. Do you want the highest value? The position of the highest value? What if that occurs twice? Etc....

Comment: I have edited it, sorry I'm still new around here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd loop over the list, without the first and last elements, and compare each element to the one before it and the one after it

```
turn = None # i.e., no turning point
for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
    if (a[i+1] > a[i] and a[i] < a[i-1]) or (a[i+1] < a[i] and a[i] > a[i-1]):
        turn = i
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **heap library**:

```
import heapq as hpq

a = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5]
turn = hpq.nlargest(a)
```